# Adding custom META tag to ActionMailer email in Rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm sending an email using an ActionMailer class in Rails 2.3.8.  I need to add a `META` tag to the `HEAD` of the email.  Specifically, I want to add this (ultimately for handling special CSS3 on mobile devices):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

I can't find a way to add this to the `HEAD` section of the email.  Do I need to create a custom email layout that I use?  If so, how do I do that?  It seems like there should be an easier way than creating a custom layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to send a HTML email and set the `meta` tag in the view. Try updating your [ActionMailer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) content-type with something like:

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default 'content-type' => 'text/html'
end
```

Then add the following line to your view's layout or `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: I'm already setting the content type to text/html.  However, ActionMailer seems to either be using an email layout or a generator that creates the HEAD section dynamically.  How can I add something into that HEAD section?

Comment: You can add a header to your email using the `headers` hash in your ActionMailer method but I think that's confusing email headers with the HTML `<head>` section. At least in my case, I have all my email HTML defined in a view used by an ActionMailer subclass and haven't noticed that ActionMailer created a default `<head>...</head>`.

Comment: I ended up having to override the <html> and <head> tags in the view itself, as you mentioned.